# How can I read a resource file in an unexploded war file deployed in Tomcat?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, maven-2, resources

I am trying to load a binary image file to do some processing inside my server-side Java code.  I am currently placing my image in the package where my executing class exists and calling:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(this.getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
```

This works fine when I'm running Tomcat on my development box in an exploded war setup, but when I deploy to a server running Tomcat where it doesn't explode war files, the call to getResource returns null.

I've also tried moving the image to my context root and accessing it like this:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(this.getClass().getResource("/../../logo.png"));
```

Again, this works on my development box, but not when I deploy it elsewhere.

Is there a better way to access this file? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: I probably should have also mentioned that I am using Maven to build my web-app.  I have a complete answer that fixes my problem, but I can't post it for 8 hours on my own question.

Comment: Put resources in your "src/main/resources" directory.
Then access them with:

    this.getClass().getResource("/logo.png");

or:

    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("logo.png");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are building using Maven, you'll want to make sure the image actually gets placed into the archive.

Put resources in your `src/main/resources` directory. Then access them with:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/logo.png");
```

or:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("logo.png");
```

(Code samples from comment above, but put in the answer to be more visible)

Comment: Please don't forget the '/' before file name in first case

Answer (score 1):

You could put your images at the root of your classpath and try this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
               .getResource("logo.png");
```

Comment: +1 - By root of your classpath, "WEB-INF/classes" inside the WAR file is where many will put said resource(s). Though they may organize by using folders like "images/logo.png" within there.